# Databinding a winform graphics with textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to draw a `Rectangle` using below code in a `Paint` event:

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x1, y1, width1, height1);
```

How do I databind the width/height of the rectangle to a `TextBox` in `Form` using c#? I want size of drawn the rectangle instantly change based on `TextBox` input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem consider these points:

1. `Rectangle` is a `struct` and you can't use it for data-binding because when setting up data-binding, your structure will pass to [`Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) object by value and all changes will be made on another instance of it. You need a class to hold properties for data-binding.
2. To be able to refresh a drawing, you should put logic of drawing in `Paint` event of your drawing surface. Then when you need to refresh drawing, call [`Invalidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx) method of your drawing surface.
3. You can redraw the rectangle immediately after changing text without using data-binding. In such case, it's enough to call `Invalidate` method of drawing surface in `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and parse entered value and use it in `Paint` event to draw rectangle.

**Example**

In this example I use a `Form` as drawing surface and define `Width1` and `Height1` properties in the `Form` and bind `TextBox` controls to these properties. I call `this.Invalidate()` in setter of properties to refresh painting on the form:

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }
    int x1, y1, width1, height1;
    public int Width1
    {
        get { return width1; }
        set { width1 = value; this.Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int Height1
    {
        get { return height1; }
        set { height1 = value; this.Invalidate(); }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x1 = 10; y1 = 10; Width1 = 100; Height1 = 100;
        this.width1TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Width1", true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        this.height1TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Height1", true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        this.Paint += ProductListForm_Paint;
    }
    void ProductListForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x1, y1, Width1, Height1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: By the way, when you accept an answer, you can also vote for post by click on up arrow near the answer. It's not compulsory at all but it's reasonable and recommended.

Comment: Sorry Reza, I tried to do that this morning but as I was new in stackflow I was not allowed to do that earlier as I was new and didn't have enough points in stackflow. Anyway I have done it now. I want to click up arrow 100 times for this answer of yours as it was a life saver for me.